# Should I use separate mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a question about storing information in a mysql database.

If i have user information, should i have separate tables to store each type of information? Or should I use 1 single table?

Let's say I have user email, username, password, first name, last name, address, gender etc...

Should I have 1 table to store email, username, and password, but another table for firstname, lastname, address and gender? Perhaps a separation from user info and account info? What do you think?

I'm not sure from a query/performance standpoint if there would be any difference by splitting up. Also, a JOIN query using the assoc. index should be able to link both tables up by User ID or some other auto increment value. Not sure what to do here!

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are specifically discouraged from Stack Overflow.  Here is some guidance on the matter:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: I apologize. Not just opinion, but from general structural rules. I'm working with laravel so i thought it might help performance to separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a *very* good reason, use [proper database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) techniques and have one table per entity type.

You're talking about a user here, so unless user and person are fundamentally different you should store that in one table.

If one user can have multiple logins, which is hopefully not the case as it tends to confuse people, then you may want to separate that out one-to-many. Otherwise, use the **simplest thing that could possibly work**.

As always, follow the advice in a guide book like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) paying **particular** attention to the part about password security.

Using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is an even better plan as that has a security model built-in that you can use.

Comment: Got it! makes sense. I'm already using the security and encryption features that laravel offers. Thanks for the concern though.

Comment: That's great, Laravel is a good foundation and has a nice database layer. When it comes to data modelling, try and think in terms of entities first and tables second. If user, login, and person are all different aspects of the same thing, that's one entity. You can always split that apart later if your definition changes.

Comment: What if i also had user balance (eg. cash or points of some type)? should that be in a separate table, or would putting it all in one be OK?

Comment: For recording things like that you want to create a proper [general ledger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_ledger) system so you can always audit it if there's any mistakes. You might keep a "balance" in the users table as an easy way to check how much they should have, but only trust the ledger when it comes to actual balances.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the functionality of your application / functionality.

But, you **should** normalise your datamodel.

Have a look at Codd, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

How many records do we talk about? Even with a few thousand, its not something to worry for. Once you get into 100K + then joins (and indexes) are getting important. And then you want to make sure your datamodel is normalised.

Comment: About 30,000 records right now. Growing though.. should i separate early for performance reasons?

Comment: 30k is nothing to any modern db

Comment: Well as i and @tadman said. You need to normalize. If you don't do this, you **will** regret that later. A datamodel, is the foundation of a good application. Don't underestimate that. I know (depending on your background) that can be *steep* learning curve. But do it, you will be very happy. Or you end-up refactoring, which is a bigger pain (probably). With todays technology you might even consider no-sql databases.